# Como criar um Dataframe em Pandas com base em duas features e mais a contagem de uma delas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Boa tarde a todos, estou realizando um projeto de análise de dados e estou com dificuldade em ponto específico.

Para facilitar o entendimento, eu tenho um DF com [1000000+ linhas x 29 colunas].

Nesse Dataframe cada linha corresponde a uma ocorrencia de uma compra, com informações referentes ao cliente e ao produto. Quero criar um novo df com 3 colunas, correspondentes respectivamente ao ID do cliente, à data de criação da conta (que são inerentes a cada usuário, ou seja, se repetem sem alteração em cada vez que o cliente realiza uma compra) e o número de vezes que esse cliente realizou compras.

Eu pensei em realizar uma união entre o `value_counts()` (para obter o número de compras de cada cliente) e o `drop_duplicates()` (para que o ID se repita apenas uma vez com sua data de criação correspondente).

O problema é que o value_counts() me retorna uma série ordenada de acordo com o número de ocorrencias, enquanto o drop_duplicates() me retorna os valores de acordo com a sua posição no DF inicial, portanto os valores ficam desencontrados.

Esse problema seria mais facilmente resolvido se eu simplesmente criasse um `n for range in (len(df)):`, mas como o DF tem mais de 1000000 registros esse processo seria muito demorado.

Alguém teria uma ideia de como realizar a criação desse df?
Desde já muito obrigado!

(PS. Eu nao sei se a minha explicação ficou confusa, se for o caso tento elaborar melhor)

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de saída esperado e dados(podem ser dados falsos somente pra simular o dataframe original), dessa forma as pessoas vão te ajudar de uma forma mais rápida. Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria legal você postar o data frame mas você poderia fazer algo assim:
`df.groupby(['|ID_Cliente','Date_Criação'], as_index=False)['Compra'].sum().sort_values(by='Compra', ascending=False)`

Supondo que `Data_Criação`seja o campo com duplicados e `Compra` seja o campo que você quer somar.

Comment: Valeu amigo!
Foi até mais simples do que eu imaginava, bastou fazer:
data_grouped = data.groupby(['user._id', 'user.created_at'], as_index=False)
data_grouped = data_grouped['_id'].count()